Robot servants pursuing girl (who is a robot too)
I'm trying to find the name of the show in an old video. A bunch of robots are crushed under a chandelier, and a girl proceeds to jump on top of another one, before she is hit in the back by some kind of headpiece(looks like a tiara, reminds me a bit of sailor moon(definitely NOT that)), only for it be revealed the girl is a robot as well as she lays there, leaking oil or something brown. Another girl then proceeds to kick off a robot's head before fleeing, with the robots in pursuit. I know the style, it was very similar to Kill la Kills style, as in an older style of anime or cartoon.
Video was in Japanese I think, but it could also have been in Spanish or some other language. The lone word I remember from it was something like Yume.
Robot servants look identical.
One of the robots is still functional, but its' missing half the skin off its face. I can't find any images of that character.
It's not from: Najica Blitz Tactics, Gintama, Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex
I don't think its from these, but I could be totally wrong: Chobits, Magical Teacher Negima, Mahoromatic, Lupin III, (From Crosspost)- Saber Marionette J or Steel Angel Kurumi
Edit: I feel like the show was from jadetru or one of their many alts on youtube. Possible from the video Female Disguise 489222.avi, but the video is long gone from youtube and I can't find it any where else. Not even the thumbnail or preview is still around so I can't find any trace of what I need.
Edit 2:Almost certain it was from that Female Disguise 489222.avi video, but no idea how to find the original thumbnail of it.
Sci-Fi Edit 1: Adding details from Reddit Post

https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/kdemfg/tomtanime2000s_show_where_robots_are_crushed_by/ - You've included lots of info on your other post that you haven't included here.
